# samba print$ share won't allow driver upload from Windows machine

Tags: samba, printer, shared-folders

I am trying to use samba together with CUPS to share printers and their drivers for Windows machines in the network.
Every time I try to upload Printer drivers from a Windows 10 machine via the printmanagement.msc I get an "Access Denied" error, but on the server side I can see, that the files have been created!

I have so far installed samba on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS workstation, created a samba user "root" with a corresponding password and edited the smb.conf

```
[print$]
    path = /srv/samba/printer_drivers/
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
    browseable = yes
    wirteable = yes
    directory mask = 0775
    create mask = 0775
    write list = @lpadmin, root
    admin users = @lpadmin, root
    force user = root
```

the shared directory /srv/samba/printer_drivers/ has the following permissions:

```
root$ ls -la /srv/samba/printer_drivers/
total 36
drwxrwsr-x 9 root root 4096 Nov  7 14:30 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov  5 10:24 ../
drwxrwsr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  7 14:30 IA64/
drwxrwsr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  7 14:30 W32ALPHA/
drwxrwsr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  7 14:30 W32MIPS/
drwxrwsr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  7 14:30 W32PPC/
drwxrwsr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  7 14:30 W32X86/
drwxrwsr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  7 14:30 WIN40/
drwxrwsr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  8 10:41 x64/
```

The subdirectories were automatically created by the Windows AddDriver Wizard

I connect the share on the Windows host via

```
net use x: \\hostname\print$ /user:root
```

I then enter the password which is accepted

```
the command completed successfully
```

I can then navigate to the share in windows explorer and create, modify and delete files without any problems.
When I open up printmanagement.msc, click on my samba server (which I added as printserver) and select "Add Driver" I am able to select a driver from the list, and click "Finish". I can then see an explorer file-transfer window that shows the files are being copied, and an ls of the shared directory on the Linux machine shows the files are there, but the windows machine then Throws an error:

"A driver HP LaserJet (...), Type 4 - Usermode x64 could not be installed. Access is denied."

As soon as I accept the error message with the OK button the driver files on the share are deleted.

The output of smbstatus (first 3 ip-address parts generalized by me):

```
root$ smbstatus
Samba version 4.7.6-Ubuntu
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
13162   root         root         *.*.*.119 (ipv4:*.*.*.119:49176) SMB3_11           -                    partial(AES-128-CMAC)

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print$       13162   *.*.*.119 Thu Nov  8 12:45:30 PM 2018 CET  -            -           
IPC$         13162   *.*.*.119 Thu Nov  8 12:45:37 PM 2018 CET  -            -           

Locked files:
Pid          Uid        DenyMode   Access      R/W        Oplock           SharePath   Name   Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
13162        0          DENY_NONE  0x80        RDONLY     NONE             /srv/samba/printer_drivers   .   Thu Nov  8 12:45:31 2018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be one of the drivers. With another version it worked. Although I have not been able to enter the printer preferences from the print management of winndows to set the default type of printing and double-sided

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled `wirteable = yes`, it should be `writeable = yes`, possibly that could fix it. But that is a wild guess, I just randomly stumbled upon.

Also, `testparm /etc/samba/smb.conf` is your friend whenever you need to check for inconsistencies on your `smb.conf` file.

Comment: And since `writeable = no ` is the default for `smb.conf` it's pretty possible that this misspelled word is what is causing the problem...